# Display All simple products of a grouped product as list view in magento product page

Tags: php, magento

i had a catalog with 29 products and when the catalog is clicked its products are to be displayed as list view as all grouped products are displayed, is there any extension for this or any help is to be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a related product.

1. Go to admin
2. select a product
3. Go to related product
4. then reset the filter and select all the rest 28 products that you want to link to that product.
5. all the related products of a product are then displayed on the product view page.

do clean your cache before testing

Comment: thanks for your resposne, for this i need to create a group product or bundle product

Comment: that is kind of categories sub-category, sub of sub-category and then the product. you will have to create categories and hierarchy in that way

Comment: then is it able to purchase a category or catalog complete